# What is the linux command to find exact size of a file in KB as reflected in WinSCP?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to find size of a file `abc.log` which shows size as `1KB` when I view it from WinSCP. These are my attempts so far -

1. `stat -c%s abc.log` - output is `2` (giving size of file content which is 2 bytes)
2. `wc -c abc.log` - output is `2`
3. `ls -l abc.log` - showing size as `2`
4. `du -h abc.log` - output is `4.0K` (this means disk space occupied by `abc.log`, right?)
5. `du -b abc.log` - output is `2`
6. `du -k abc.log` - output is `4`

But what command would give me output as `1k` or `1` at least as that is the size which is showing under the "Size" column in WinSCP? (On copying the file in Windows machine also it is showing `1KB`)

I have tried `find -name abc.log -size 1k` and it gave me output as `abc.log` meaning that it has detected the size of `abc.log` as `1kB`.

I am not understanding where `1k` is appearing from because even commands like `du` are not showing `1k`. But I need a command such that when I pass filename as input it would give me the file size exactly as shown in WinSCP and as detected by the `find` command.

Comment: So you want us to find a command that measures the size as incorrectly as WinSCP? Wouldn't it be better to find a setting in WinSCP that gives you an accurate size?

Comment: `find -name abc.log -size 1k` doesn’t match files exactly 1k in size, because `-size` with a unit rounds up; so `-size 1k` matches files with sizes between 1 byte and 1024 bytes inclusive.

Comment: https://winscp.net/tracker/1530 implements a requirement to round up to the next sized unit. Maybe `find` will indeed suffice

Comment: Where does the value which appears in the Size column of the remote as viewed from WinSCP appear from and what is the linux command to get it? Does it show the size of the content present in the file or does it show the disk space usage? (it matches neither with the disk space usage nor with the file content size value). Even on copying the file to my Windows local it shows size as 1KB. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Use: `echo $(( ( $( stat -c %s abc.log ) + 1023) / 1024 ))k`. WinSCP just gives the size in 1k units rounded like this -- no connection to physical blocks.